# What is the URL for force creating new Xero OAuth 1.0 applications?

Tags: xero-api

I have several dozen offices that haven't migrated to OAuth 2.0 yet. One of these offices I transferred to another subscriber, and the app needs to utilize 1.0 until we can migrate. I recall being able to create Oauth 1.0 apps after 2.0 was implemented by using a URL parameter, but I can't recall the actual parameter. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Contact the support team on api@xero.com and they'll help you out

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.xero.com/myapps?privateAppCreation=true

This will work until the end of June 2020.